# Unkown ip adress in my lan

Tags: wifi, network-scanners, mac-address

While scanning my LAN with Angry IP Scanner, I found an ip @ that I didn't recognise 192.168.1.59:

> IP              Ping            Hostname                MAC Address                      MAC Vendor
>
> 192.168.1.10    0 ms            DESKTOP-F126TH4         48:5F:99:46:XX:XX                CloudTechnology               // Laptop
>
> 192.168.1.100   3 ms            [n/a]                   C4:71:54:B8:XX:XX                TP-LINK                       //Router
>
> 192.168.1.59    0 ms            [n/a]                   E8:6A:64:D4:XX:XX                LCFCTechnology                // ??
>
> 192.168.1.2     51 ms           [n/a]                   [n/a]                            [n/a]                         // Smartphone

My router is the .100, the .59 doesn't appear in my router dhcp table and I can only ping it through my laptop (.10), I changed my wifi password but the same device show up immediately after, I disabled wifi on my router and connected through a Ethernet cable and still the .59 show up.

Any idea what it could be ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the network adapter that is connecting to your network using the MAC address that you show is likely made by LCFC(HeFei) Electronics, as some of the network adapters that they produce have MAC addresses in the E8:6A:64:xx:xx:xx range.  See https://udger.com/resources/mac-address-vendor-detail?name=lcfchefei_electronics_technology_co-ltd.

If you don't recognize this device, see [Unknown MAC address connected to router](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/unknown-mac-address-connected-to-router) for some ideas as to how to proceed next.